# Kerio Connect: Delegated users can accept meetings on behalf of user. Unwanted behaviour

Tags: kerio

Meeting requests can be accepted on behalf of a user by others who are sharing her calender, and this is undesired behavior.

Is there anyway that this can be changed, so that other users have visibility of the calender, can make changes, just not accept meeting requests,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the user has been playing around with their permissions, and had assigned read and write permissions to their account